# Barrier Statue of the Abyss and Barrier Statue of the Heavens -- A Contradiction?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

If both of these cards are on the field, how are their effects resolved?

**Barrier Statue of the Abyss**(Effect Monster)
*No monsters can be Special Summoned, except for DARK monsters.*

**Barrier Statue of the Heavens** (Effect Monster)
*No monsters can be Special Summoned, except for LIGHT monsters.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***No Monsters can be Special Summoned.*** Both Monsters have a [Continuous Effect](http://www.yugioh-card.com/uk/rulebook/V7_English_Rlbk_lores.pdf) (page 14 of PDF) that is active while they are on the field. BSotAbyss blocks all non-DARK Monsters from being special summoned, so when you Attempt to Special Summon a DARK Monster, it is BSotHeaven that blocks you, and vice versa when you Special Summon a LIGHT Monster, it is BSotAbyss that blocks you.

> This effect is active while the Effect Monster Card is face-up on the field. The effect starts when the face-up monster appears on the field, and ends once that monster is gone or is no longer face-up; [...]

The Barrier Statues [prevent any Special Summoning](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Barrier_Statue_of_the_Abyss), unless the Monster is of a matching Atribute (page 11).

> [Barrier Statue of the Abyss](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Barrier_Statue_of_the_Abyss) - No monsters can be Special Summoned, except for DARK monsters.
>
> [Barrier Statue of the Heavens](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Barrier_Statue_of_the_Heavens) - No monsters can be Special Summoned, except for LIGHT monsters.

Comment: Good!  I like the response!  Is it fair to say if a monster is both "Dark" AND "Light" then you could summon it?  I know of at least one monster that *becomes* both attributes *once* on the field, but it couldn't enter the field because from the hand it is only light.  Are there cards which are both of these attributes in your hand, because then you could summon such a card because if you combine these effects it reads "No monsters can be Special Summoned, except for "Dark and Light" monsters", as in they must have BOTH attributes.

Comment: @Squirtle, I know of no such card with dual attributes, but if it existed, it could be special summoned with both Barrier Statues on the field. You **don't combine** the card effects, a DARK or LIGHT monster couldn't be Special Summoned (SS) because the opposite Barrier Statue prevents it. A DARK & LIGHT monster could be SS, because it has a quality that exempts it **from both** Barrier Statues.

Comment: Yes!  When I said "combine" I meant their "intersection" not their union.... or in this case, the union of their constraints.